# Execute group of functions parallel/serially using Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

There is table as below, which contains all function/method names from MyRunnable class,
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrqM5.jpg)

so for a rfc, I want to execute all the groups in sequence,
But within each group the functions will run parallel/serially depending on parallel flag.

for group#1 >Main java > shld spawn FNC1, FNC33 in parallel threads,
FNC12 should only start once above threads complete as marked as parallel N
and on completion of previous thread > FNC343,FNC892 should execute parallely.

group 2> both are marked N for parallel, so its serial threads.

group 3> execute FNC31 serially,
FNC32 marked manual, so any number of function above manual step should complete and code should exit..

so  in my Main Class, 
within a for-loop which iterates over each group# ,each row from the result set >GOes into a if-loop to check if Skipped and create a worker as below, in MyRunnable methods are invoked using reflections.

```
worker = new MyRunnable(met_name,met_num,rfc_num);
executor.execute(worker);
```

MyRunnable snippet :

```
 public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
 private String mname;
 protected int rfc_num;
 protected int met_num;

public MyRunnable() {
    // Do nothing - no args constructor

}

public MyRunnable(String mname,int met_num,int rfc_num) {
    this.mname=mname;
    this.rfc_num=rfc_num;
    this.met_num=met_num;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected static void FNC12(int mnum,int rnum){ System.out.println("Running code for FNC12");}

   // All other functions here

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("INSIDE RUN:"+mname+" "+rfc_num+" "+met_num);
    Method Call_met;
    try {
            Class<?> base = Class.forName("test.MyRunnable");
            Call_met = base.getDeclaredMethod(mname, int.class,int.class);
            System.out.println(mname+" "+rfc_num+" "+met_num);
            Call_met.invoke(base.newInstance(),met_num,rfc_num);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}

}
```

As of now, i am not able to stop/complete the threads once a "parallel NO" is encountered within a group
or run parallel N functions serially in a new threads. can anyone please help with the code or logic ?

Comment: sorry, do not ave time to dig deeper but maybe you should investigate ThreadPoolExecutor class: yous could create as many threadPool as groups you have and submit your job to the pool. For NO parallelism, you could use a TreadPool of size 1 (hence task would be sequential) and for parallelism you could use a large thread pool. Hope it may help...

Comment: yes.. i started reading about it, my issue comes when  in group of 10 methods, i might have just 1-2 within the group which are Parallel NO, so need to split the methods into sets of initial parallel, serial, parallel groups

Answer (score 0):

Consuder the use of an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). It eliminates the need to manually create/start/join Threads. Use the pattern in the main method for the parallel parts of your work.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q51518249;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MultiThreading {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();

        // execute 10 tasks
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pool.execute(new MyRunnable(i));
        }

        pool.awaitQuiescence(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static final class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final int number;

        public MyRunnable(final int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + number + " started.");

            // business logic

            System.out.println("Thread " + number + " finished.");
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce an output something like:

```
Thread 0 started.
Thread 1 started.
Thread 2 started.
Thread 3 started.
Thread 2 finished.
Thread 4 started.
Thread 1 finished.
Thread 5 started.
Thread 5 finished.
Thread 6 started.
Thread 3 finished.
Thread 7 started.
Thread 0 finished.
Thread 8 started.
Thread 8 finished.
Thread 9 started.
Thread 4 finished.
Thread 7 finished.
Thread 6 finished.
Thread 9 finished.
```

Comment: i am already using ExecutorService in the code,
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS); 
     .... 
     worker = new MyRunnable(met_name,met_num,RFC_NUM);
     executor.execute(worker); 

My problem is to wait for the threads to stop within a group, as next method is parallel no (serial).. and then go back to running serial or parallel depending on the result set